# Using a numeric identifier for value selection in click.Choice

Tags: python-click

The [Click](http://click.palletsprojects.com) package allows a range of values to be selected from a list using the [click.Choice](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.Choice) method.

In my case the values are relatively long strings, so using:

```py
    choice_names = [u'Vulnerable BMC (IPMI)', u'IoT Vulnerability', u'SMBv1', u'BadHTTPStatus', u'Compromised']

    @click.option('--category', prompt='\nPlease enter the category of incident.\n\n -- Options:\n{}\n\n'.format(
        format_choices(choice_names)), type=click.Choice(choice_names))
```

will list the values as:

```
-> Vulnerable BMC (IPMI)
-> IoT Vulnerability
-> SMBv1
-> BadHTTPStatus
-> Compromised
```

This requires the user to enter the full string, which is inconvenient. Does Click provide a functionality to select a value using only a numeric identifier? So, the above options could be listed as:

```
-> Vulnerable BMC (IPMI) [1]
-> IoT Vulnerability [2]
-> SMBv1 [3]
-> BadHTTPStatus [4]
-> Compromised [5]
```

and to select the first option, the user would need to enter `1`. This could be possible by defining a custom validation function, but I couldn't find any existing functionality offered by Click.

Answer (score 7):

I came up with this:

```py
class ChoiceOption(click.Option):
    def __init__(self, param_decls=None, **attrs):
        click.Option.__init__(self, param_decls, **attrs)
        if not isinstance(self.type, click.Choice):
            raise Exception('ChoiceOption type arg must be click.Choice')

        if self.prompt:
            prompt_text = '{}:\n{}\n'.format(
                self.prompt,
                '\n'.join(f'{idx: >4}: {c}' for idx, c in enumerate(self.type.choices, start=1))
            )
            self.prompt = prompt_text

    def process_prompt_value(self, ctx, value, prompt_type):
        if value is not None:
            index = prompt_type(value, self, ctx)
            return self.type.choices[index - 1]

    def prompt_for_value(self, ctx):
        # Calculate the default before prompting anything to be stable.
        default = self.get_default(ctx)

        prompt_type = click.IntRange(min=1, max=len(self.type.choices))
        return click.prompt(
            self.prompt, default=default, type=prompt_type,
            hide_input=self.hide_input, show_choices=False,
            confirmation_prompt=self.confirmation_prompt,
            value_proc=lambda x: self.process_prompt_value(ctx, x, prompt_type))

@click.command()
@click.option('--hash-type', prompt='Hash', type=click.Choice(['MD5', 'SHA1'], case_sensitive=False), cls=ChoiceOption)
def cli(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

Result:

```
> cli --help
Usage: cli [OPTIONS]                          

Options:                                           
  --hash-type [MD5|SHA1]                           
  --help                  Show this message and exit.

> cli --hash-type MD5
{'hash_type': 'MD5'}

> cli
Hash:                                              
  1: MD5                                          
  2: SHA1                                         
: 4                                                
Error: 4 is not in the valid range of 1 to 2.      
Hash:                                              
  1: MD5                                          
  2: SHA1                                         
: 2                                                
{'hash_type': 'SHA1'}
```

Edit May 25, 2020:
I recently came across [questionary](https://github.com/tmbo/questionary) and integrated it with `click`

```py
import click
import questionary


class QuestionaryOption(click.Option):

    def __init__(self, param_decls=None, **attrs):
        click.Option.__init__(self, param_decls, **attrs)
        if not isinstance(self.type, click.Choice):
            raise Exception('ChoiceOption type arg must be click.Choice')

    def prompt_for_value(self, ctx):
        val = questionary.select(self.prompt, choices=self.type.choices).unsafe_ask()
        return val



@click.command()
@click.option('--hash-type', prompt='Hash', type=click.Choice(['MD5', 'SHA1'], case_sensitive=False), cls=QuestionaryOption)
def cli(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 1):

Since Click does not seem to provide a functionality of this kind, this custom validation function fulfills the purpose:

```py
def validate_choice(ctx, param, value):
    # Check if the passed value is an integer.
    try:
        index = int(value) - 1
        # Return the value at the given index.
        try:
            return choice_names[index]
        # If the index does not exist.
        except IndexError:
            click.echo('Please select a valid index.')
    # If the value is of a different type, for example, String.
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        # Return the value if it exists in the list of choices.
        if value in choice_names:
            return value
        else:
            click.echo('Please select a valid value from the choices {}.'.format(choice_names))

    # Prompt the user for an input.
    value = click.prompt(param.prompt)
    return validate_choice(ctx, param, value)

@click.option('--category', prompt='\nPlease enter the category.\n\n -- Options:\n{}\n\n'.format(choice_names),
              help='Category of the incident', callback=validate_category)
```

This allows a user to select a choice either by entering the choice name or by entering the index value. In case an invalid value is entered, the user is prompted again for an input.

Comment: This code prompts during validation, yet validation will be run when this value is specified from the command line.  But generally prompting only happens when a value is not specified.  So this seems to be mixing concerns.

Comment: The help would be shown similar to other commands (I have updated my code).

Actually, the code prompts for input only if the validation fails. But I agree that this part should be separated from the `validate_choice()` function, but I don't believe Click provides any other way of doing this.

Comment: @StephenRauch On a different note, is there a way of manually passing the context (`ctx`) to a function? Currently I have the `validate_choice()` function duplicated in different files. So instead of writing `callback=validate_category`, is there a way of doing `callback=validate_category(ctx, param, ...)`?